# How to insert a text box at any position in the picture, like in MS Paint, in processing?

Tags: text, processing, draw

I'm trying to create a program where, like MS Paint, I can insert text anywhere in the picture or sketch (in processing) and is able to write whatever desired. Writing text within the code is simple but my struggle is to actually write the text in the sketch.

This is my code:

```
PFont f;
String textVar = "";

void setup() {
size(200,200);
f = createFont("Arial",16,true);
}

void draw() {
background(255);
textFont(f,16);                 
fill(0);
text (textVar, mouseX, mouseY);  
}

void keyPressed() {
if (key == BACKSPACE) {
if (textVar.length() > 0) {
  textVar = textVar.substring(0,textVar.length() - 1);
}
}
else if (textWidth(textVar+key) < width) {
textVar = textVar + key;
}
}
```

Comment: Please be more specific.What programming language?,What have you tried by now?.And note this site is not for spoon feeding.

Comment: +ShihabSoft I wouldn't ask if I haven't tried. The language is java and all I know with adding text in a sketch is calling the text() function and using strings.

Comment: Yes if you have tried.Then post the Java code that you have tried by now.Anyway as you are a newbie.I will help you.

Comment: +ShihabSoft I just entered my somewhat attempt in writing the code.

Answer (score 0):

Using `mousePressed()` function you can store position of you text simple

```
void mousePressed() {
  X = mouseX;
  Y = mouseY;
}
```

So you just change `text()` parameters to:

```
text (textVar, X, Y);
```

If you want more different positions of text box you will need to use collections. To do so create `class textBox` with attributes: positionX, positionY and text where you can store all importatnt information. Then simply add this to collection:

```
ArrayList<textBox> boxes = new ArrayList();
```

Then you can add counter within `mousePressed` function to create new object of `textBox` and add it to collection of `boxes`:

```
boxes.add( new textBox(mouseX, mouseY, textVar))
```

And within you `draw()` function you will have to draw all you boxes:

```
for (textBox b: boxes)   b.printB();
```

Where `printB()` is method of class textBox and simply draw your text on desired position.